# How can I redirect a 404 Error in a custom 404 page using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Kind sirs,
I'm using Codeigniter to build a blog. I might need a way to redirect a 404 error into a custom 404 page. Just like what Abduzeedo.com's 404 page. Is it possible to control this by using routes? Or should i use controllers to direct it to another view? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

there is another way which I use: by overriding Exception core class of Codeigniter. Firstly make sure your config file(system/application/config/config.php) subclass prefix is as following
`$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';`

Then make a file named MY_Exceptions.php in system/application/libraries. Then override the function show_404() function here as follows.

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions{
    function MY_Exceptions(){
        parent::CI_Exceptions();
    }

    function show_404($page=''){    

        $this->config =& get_config();
        $base_url = $this->config['base_url'];

        $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Error message';
        header("location: ".$base_url.'error.html');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now Error controller will be your error page, where the page will be redirected for 404 error.

Answer (score 10):

Custom **404 page** is create by using the following **3 steps**,

**Step 1**: First open routes.php in application/config and set a custom controller name,

```
$route['404_override'] = 'my404'; //my404 is class name.
```

**Step 2**: Create a new controller and write the following code in it. The code is very easy to understand. So I am not going to explain it here,

```
    <?php 
class my404 extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 

    public function index() 
    { 
        $this->output->set_status_header('404'); 
        $data['content'] = 'error_404'; // View name 
        $this->load->view('index',$data);//loading in my template 
    } 
    } 
    ?>
```

**Step 3**: Create a view file with name '**error_404.php**' with your custom message.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create any controller or modify the code, rather than modify one view file. Just placed your 404 page HTML into the `application/views/errors/html/error_404.php` file.

If you want to use base_url() or any other CodeIgniter functions, initialize CI_Controller class like the below code.

```
<?php
  $ci = new CI_Controller();
  $ci =& get_instance();
  $ci->load->helper('url');
?>
```

Comment: This was actually the best for me. I couldn't get the 404 controller to work, but this allowed me to access my models and my views and do what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: In CI 2.2 you can just edit your page but for 3.0 we initialize ci_contoller as you defined (y)

Answer (score 3):

For a simple solution, go to your "error_404.php" file in "application/errors/" directory and put this code at the beginning of the file:

```
header("Location:".base_url());
```

It'll redirect your 404 page to home page.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Solution.**

Create your custom error or Page not found page within view.

Create a controller for error page. Within index function load the view of error page that you already created in previous step.

Now, Go to your `application/config/routes.php`

you should find `$route['404_override'] = '';`

Its the `''` mean its calling the default error page.

Now place your controller name for error page .

It will work.

Suppose my Controller for error page is `'error'`. and view page is `'notfound'` .

So, code for `Error.php` controller will be:

```
<?php
class Error extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
        {
           $this->load->view('notfound'); 
        }

}
```

Now, I replaced  `$route['404_override'] = '';` to `$route['404_override'] = 'error';`   in 
`application/config/routes.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you want to show your custom 404page when page not found in your website you just replace your custom file on core file which is located in `application/error/error_404.php` just replace your file here and you are good to go else where you can follow other method by using `routes` and custom controller for you custom `404 page`. But the shortest and easiest way is replacing the core file with custom `404error page` file

Answer (score 1):

First open routes.php in the application/config folder and set a custom controller name.

```
 $route['404_override'] = 'custom404'; //custom404 is class name.
```

Create a new controller and write the following code in it. The code is very easy to understand. So I am not going to explain it here.

```
<?php 
class custom404 extends CI_Controller 
{
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct(); 
} 

public function index() 
{ 
    $this->output->set_status_header('404'); 
    $data['content'] = 'error_404'; // View name 
    $this->load->view('index',$data);//loading in my template 
} 
 } 
 ?>
```

Create a view file with name 'error_404.php' with your custom message.
That is all you need to do and will be having your custom 404 page now.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple solution:
Just edit `/application/views/error_404.php` with your custom 404 page :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to define any complexity. 
The process is very simple.
First, go to your application->config->routes.php file and change this with your controller's function, where you simply load the header, footer, and 404.php page.

```
$route['404_override'] = 'welcome/_404';
```

Then come to your controller's page

```
function _404(){
$this->load->view("header");
$this->load->view("404");
$this->load->view("footer");
```

}

The same question is also available here
[Display a view for 404 error in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758275/display-a-view-for-404-error-in-codeigniter)