# how to make a custom error_php.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I redirect a 404 Error in a custom 404 page using Codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310061/how-can-i-redirect-a-404-error-in-a-custom-404-page-using-codeigniter)

all... i'm new in igniter...All i am trying to work on is to how to make a custom error page..The error_php.php file causes showing all the errors appearing in a file get displayed.

I want to create a page somewhat like error_404.php file which, when will face any php error will display a white page. the show_error file in the Exception.php displays error message for each error.. I want just a page total white page displaying "Technical Problem"/. Can anybody help me out.. I dont even have the idea of how to proceed

Comment: You may edit the error pages to your likes, at `application/error/` folder

Comment: the error_404 pages open as another page, but the error_php appears on the page where the error occurs..if error is on the link localhost/sai_boutique/payment then the error_php apperas on the definite page, and also no of occurrence as the no. of errors. i want a simple white page, not showing any error just a message

Comment: You're saying you want the warnings to disappear? You would most likely want to edit the "environment" variable located in the `index.php` file and set it to 'production'. It'll remove all errors from displaying on your website.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `application/config/routes.php` and modify `$config['404_override']` to include the controller and controller function you want for your 404 page.

Create a controller with the following.

```
function Error extends CI_Controller 
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('404_page');
    }
}
```

Create a new view called `404_page` which now contains the custom 404 content that you want!

Comment: i'm asking about creation error_php.php page..not eror_404 page

Comment: By default, you can't create a page that will remove all the warnings on your page and load a different view. You can however hide them by the comment I made in your question.

Comment: well, interestingly i want to make a comment, i did creat a new error_php.php in my codeigniter application, and remaned the old error_php.php into error_php1.php.   i just did what i desired to do, and if anybody interested, then i can post the code..