# Redirect when wrong parameter in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

E.g. I have a working url:

```
http://localhost/article/154
```

Where 154 is **$id** of the article in db and a controller **article** looks like e.g.:

```
function index ($id = '')
{

// some code here

}
```

Now, when I type something like:

```
http://localhost/article/154dsdead34
```

I get error because that id is not in my db. But, the php errors are shown on the page and the whole page is messedd up.

Instead I need a redirect to my controller called **custom404** that can handle this (or if it is for some reason not possible at least a direct redirect('/'); to the homepage)

The same fix for variants like (to big $id number or not found in db):

```
http://localhost/article/3004534534534234600234
```

or (other parameters)

```
http://localhost/article/154/something/derer/asdasd
```

how to do such security check in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many ways to do this.

Inside the function, define `($id = NULL)` so it skips empty errors, and the 1st statement can be `if ( ! is_numeric($id)) show_404();`

You could also run `$id = (int)$id;` which should turn `154dsdead34` into `154`.

Routing is an option aswell. What would you prefer?

You could do like this; inside the function run:

```
if ( ! preg_match("~^article/\d+$~", $this->uri->uri_string())) {
    // Redirect user
}
```

Change accordingly. `~` opens and closes the regex. it's often `/`, but with like `~` you don't have to escape `/` (`\/`). `^` is the beginning of the string and `$` is the end. `\d+` is equal to `[0-9]+` and requires cases with one digit or more. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: What about localhost/article/154/somehtingwrong/blablabla/eee type of link ? Now, it throws errors.

Comment: Routes are imho the easiest, but I am not sure how to do that condition into regex. I mean only id (id check in db I can handle in controller) after article/ is allowed and everything else like /asdasdsad/asdasd/asda is not. any advice?

Comment: Added another solution with explaination. Just for curiosity, what does it matter if those random urls work? is it for potential SEO optimization?

Comment: it is not working ;( . link like article/154/somehtingwrong/blablabla/eee throws errors ;(

Comment: Finally! your sulution is working. However, I needed to change in my routes from $route['article/(:num)'] = 'article/$1'; to $route['article/(:any)'] = 'article/$1'; . So num to any with your preg_match will make the WIN. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Through the routes.php in config folder, to check for the 6 digit numeric only you need use

```
$route['article/([0-9]{1,6})'] = 'article/$1' ;
```

and mention all other cases to 404 or send to any other controller

Comment: Not working. I need a redirect if it is wrong. Your suggestion is identical to my old: $route['article/(:num)'] = 'article/$1' ; It is not helping at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "and mention all other cases to 404 or send to any other controller"? My current in routes.php is $route['404_override'] = 'custom404'; How can I change it?

Comment: Oh for the custom404 take a look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310061/how-can-i-redirect-a-404-error-in-a-custom-404-page-using-codeigniter)

Comment: I know that. I need to ignore the other parts if somebody write them e.g. instead of the good link localhost/article/154/ he writes somethink like: localhost/article/154/somehtingwrong/blablabla/eee and I need to ignore the part after the id. I mean this part: /somehtingwrong/blablabla/eee