# base_url() function won't work on error pages. Even after autoloading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to have nice good looking error pages. For this I need to get some CSS and JS files. But for some odd reason using `base_url()` does not work on the error_pages. I could of course just use `href="/css/style.css"` and tell it to get it from the root folder. But the website could very well be put in a different folder than the root folder. So using the `/` is not an option.

So my question now is why doesn't `base_url()` work on an error page? I have autoloaded it so shouldn't it be working?

This is what I tried when I was trying to get the base_url() from the error_404 page in the view.

In my autoload.php I have included the helper `url`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

And in my error_404 page (application/views/errors/html/error_404.php) I am echoing the base_url like so:

`<?php echo base_url(); ?>`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function base_url()

Filename: /usr/local/www/example.com/application/views/errors/html/error_404.php

Line Number: 37

Backtrace:

    File: /usr/local/www/example.com/index.php
    Line: 315
    Function: require_once
```

I'd rather not make any changes in the `system` folder since I don't want to redo the process every time I update Codeigniter folder.

System:

> Codeigniter 3.0.6
>
> PHP 7.0.8
>
> Nginx 1.11.1

**UPDATE:**
I'd like to call base_url on every error page (db, 404, general, php, etc.).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310061/how-can-i-redirect-a-404-error-in-a-custom-404-page-using-codeigniter Please have a look at this.

Comment: That will definitely work. But isn't it overkill? Creating a custom class just to show base_url()? I will wait a bit to see other answers.

Comment: And what about the other error_pages? The above comment would only work for the 404 page am I correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The autoloader does not work because the autoloader loads the libraries ***after*** the error checks are finished. If there are errors like a `404 not found` it will view the custom error page without loading the autoloader.

To get your base_url on a custom page you would need to add the following in your custom error page:

```
$base_url = load_class('Config')->config['base_url'];
```

Taken from:
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-65968-post-335822.html#pid335822

Answer (score 1):

You must load the helper class to get access url functions. So, try to do first:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then you can echo it using

```
echo base_url();
```

alternatively, you can get the same result with

```
$this->config->config['base_url'];
```

Comment: Where would I load the helper URL for an error page that is automatically called whenever I visit a URL that does not exist? Also what's the points of using autoload if I still need to load it manually?

Comment: You can load the helper in `application/config/autoload.php`, but why are you trying to achieve this manually? The `error_404` page is automatically called when a controller is not found.

Comment: That's the problem. The helper is **already** in the `autoload.php`. And I still can't call the `base_url()`. Same goes for your alternative.

Comment: How about if you tried to get the instance of CI as `$ci =& get_instance();` in your view, or where-ever you want to get the base_url from.

Comment: I've done the following: in the view `$ci =& get_instance();` and echoed it as `var_dump($ci->config->item['base_url']);` It returns the following error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: I think CI checks whether the controller and function exists and if it does not it will immediately skip autoloading and just load the 404 page

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this ,You must override the error pages in your routes.php file something like

```
$route['404_override'] = 'controller/method';
```

And inside `method()` function,You can access `base_url()` after loading uri helper as same as normal codeigniter controller.

```
$this->load->helper('uri');
echo base_url();
```

if we need to  change the design of other php/db error pages.we can edit the following files
[image]

Comment: How would I be able to override a database error page? Or a PHP error page?

Comment: for 404 error pages,the above code is fine.I override other errors by editing the core files.Which version of CI you are using?

Comment: It's fine for 404 pages but not for the other ones. I'd rather not edit out core files because if there is a new version of CodeIgniter with important security issues, I would not like to waste time because I have to port code to the core files. CodeIgniter version is 3.0.6.

Comment: I can change the design that's not the problem. The problem is that I can't call the base_url() through these error_pages.

Comment: You can try to include the config files into the error pages ,And you can get the values from the defined array.I think that would help you\