# Codeigniter3.1.2 base_url() not working in views/errors/html/error_404.php

Tags: codeigniter

`base_url()` works correctly in my controller but it does not work in `views/errors/html/error_404.php`.

I have autoloaded the url helper. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow. It would be useful to include your code for `views/errors/html_error_404.php` and the error you are getting (or the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour if there is no error message)

Comment: Base url helper is not available in error pages, these helpers loaded after error checks. You have to do a workaround, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048365/base-url-function-wont-work-on-error-pages-even-after-autoloading