# Is it possible to redirect all types of error to a common page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, error-handling, codeigniter-2

Is it possible redirect all following error page contents to a common page?
normally codeigniter packages include following pages for error handling:

application->views->errors->html (error_exception.php, error_db.php, error_general.php, error_php.php, error_404.php)
Is it possible to redirect these contents to a common page?

Comment: Maybe help this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310061/how-can-i-redirect-a-404-error-in-a-custom-404-page-using-codeigniter

Comment: @dekts is this handle all types of errors, means db, php, 404, exception etc....

Comment: you can create your custom page for displaying error and change redirect of view from (error_exception.php, error_db.php, error_general.php, error_php.php, error_404.php)

Answer (score 0):

Code Igniter has some error logging functions built in.

- Make your /application/logs folder writable
- In /application/config/config.php set 
  $config['log_threshold'] = 1;
  or use a higher number, depending on how much detail you want in your logs
- Use log_message('');

see more http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

Use try...catch and redirect everything to one page using header.

```
try {
   //code
} catch( Exception $e ) {
   echo "friendly error message";
   logging_function($e->getMessage());
   throw $e;
}
```