# CodeIgniter: 404_override route not working for undefined controller method

Tags: php, codeigniter

In `config/routes.php` I set `$route['404_override']='myerrorcontroller/amethod'` and it works for undefined controller class. My error controller class is called.

But if the controller exists while the method is not (eg. `http://localhost/myexistingcontroller/myundefinedmethod`), the 404 page is CodeIgniter's default (http://www.apnacode.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/codeigniter_404.png).

[image]

How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your project's folder name?

Comment: you can [override Exception core class of Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310061/how-can-i-redirect-a-404-error-in-a-custom-404-page-using-codeigniter), which will effectively replace all Codeigniter 404 page

Comment: @NaimMalek: anything to do with this issue?